# Socket is Connected or not in dealing with EASYMODBUS in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, real-time-data, easy-modbus

I am using "EasyModBus" to communicate with a BUS system. I need the user to be aware immediately if connection lost or is getting down. Another issue is that if i disconnect the network, the software will get hang due to a non-connected Socket on the below mentioned line:

```
ushort[] inputs = master1.ReadHoldingRegisters(startAddress, numInputs);
```

I tested several ways listed bellow:

1. if(tcpClient.Connected)
2. if(tcpClient.Available!=0) and also socket.Poll
3. Pinging and check status

***result:***
Pinging is ok but, i have to change my reading time interval from 1000ms to at least 2500ms. Then, if i disconnect the socket, i get the exception. But i need to read pules every 1000ms.

There is the same question here: EasyModbus: disconnecting from network doesn't change the connection state

As i mentioned, i tried tcpclient.Available but, it does not work.

My Codes:

```
private NetWork _NetWork = null;
        bool PingSlave(IPAddress slaveIPB)
        {
            PingReply reply = _NetWork.SendPing(slaveIPB,2500);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }


 void Master1_Slave1_Read()
        {
            try
            {
                ipAddressTCP1 = tBxIPAdrs.Text.ToString();
                tcpClient1 = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient1.Connect(ipAddressTCP1, ipPortTCP1);
                master1 = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(tcpClient1);
                ushort startAddress = 0;
                ushort numInputs = 10;

                if (PingSlave(ipS) == true)
                {
                    ushort[] inputs = master1.ReadHoldingRegisters(startAddress, numInputs);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
                    {
                        if (inputs != null)
                            rTBx0_IOMF.AppendText(inputs[i].ToString() + "\t");
                    }

                    rTBx0_IOMF.AppendText("\n");
                }
                else
                    rTBx1_IOMF.AppendText("\n" + "Warning:\t\t Check Your Connection!" + "\t\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy:HH:mm:ss") + "\n");
            }
            catch (EasyModbus.Exceptions.ConnectionException ex)
            {
                rTBx0_IOMF.AppendText(ex.Message.ToString() + "\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                rTBx0_IOMF.AppendText(ex.Message.ToString() + "\n");
            }

           }

private void t0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Master1_Slave1_Read();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Learn the 7 Network Layers.  The picture you show is the hardware layer for connecting into an Ethernet network which has nothing to do with your question.  Each device on the Network has an IP address and you will use TCP to connect to an IP.  Then get manual on each sensor and see the command to read the status.  You did not give a part number for the sensors, just the Ethernet router.

Comment: TCP, by design, will not report disconnects at lower layers without additional effort on your part. Your "ping" approach is one option, another is to enable "keep-alive" for the connection. See duplicate.

Comment: I solved this and this not duplicated. KeepAlive is not proper for every second check. If you undelete i will share my answer.